# Is there a way to use AWS KMS for key management with SSH in Jenkins on Windows?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh, amazon-kms

We have a Jenkins setup under Windows that has a master and a worker instance, and each instance runs on EC2 in AWS.  We set up a separate account in each instance and that account is used to run the Jenkins service on each instance.  We used Git bash to generate keys via SSH and copied the public key to Bitbucket, allowing the master instance to get the Jenkinsfile from the repository and allowing the worker instance to get the whole repository for the build.  Currently, we generate the keys manually and they sit on the server (which is behind our firewall), but to keep things simple for the script, the keys lack a passphrase.  Our comfort level with this is quite low, so we are looking at other options.  We know that AWS has KMS which would allow us to generate and rotate our keys, but we are not sure how to wire up ssh with AWS KMS.  Any advice or ideas would be appreciated, either in regards to AWS KMS and SSH, or a better way to keep the keys secure.

Answer (score 1):

YES! It is possible to use KMS to store your keys but the process is not straight forward as you have described. KMS indeed only generates and manages the keys used to encrypt or decrypt stuff so you will need to develop a middleware like a platform to interacts with KMS and orchestrate this process.

On Fugue blog there's an example of how to use KMS to store database passwords:
https://blog.fugue.co/2015-04-21-aws-kms-secrets.html

On the example, credstash is the middleware/platform orchestrating the steps to get and store the database password. You can also use credtstash to securely store the ssh keys and retrieve it again on the jenkins server. The transport of the password will be secured by the credstash.

Steps:

1) generate the ssh keys
2) use credstash to put the ssh key string into dynamo (credstash uses dynamo DB to store the encrypted data)
3) use credstash to get the ssh key and write it to jenkins.